# Best practice for notating harmonic: quarter vs. half note?

Tags: notation, harmonics

Typically, an "open diamond" notehead is used to indicate a harmonic fingering.  The image here is from an edition of the Cassado Cello Suite (1st mov't).  It's clear from the overall context that the last note is a harmonic half-note, but visually it's the same as if it were a harmonic quarter-note.  Just wondering if there's any consensus as to alternative notations that explicitly indicate the distinction between the two note-lengths? [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case the intent is clear.

In one of the standard works on notation, ["Behind Bars"](http://www.behindbarsnotation.co.uk/) by Elaine Gould, the author writes:

> The diamond remains hollow, regardless of its duration. Where the rhythm is not clear from its context, differentiate minims and crochets *[half and quarter notes]* by writing the rhythmic values as small notes in brackets over the stave.

[image]